# ie 10 does not read the cookie added to the response

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, internet-explorer-10

In my spring mvc application i have implementating [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser.aspx) solution based on a cookie to detect a file download finish by javascript. Its works fine in firefox and chrome but in IE 10 the cookie that is added to the header of the response is undefined when is read in the javascript. furthermore if the validation of the method of the controller returns an error and the method is called again the IE 10 browser reads the cookie perfectly. Can someone explain this behavior of IE 10?

my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("print")
public String print(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute InvoiceFilter filter, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response) {

    new InvoiceValidator().validate(filter, result);

    if (result.hasErrors()) {       
        return "/invoices";
    }   

    String fileDownloadToken = request.getParameter("fileDownloadToken");
    invoiceService.exportInvoice(baos, filter, logData);                                                    
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment;filename=Invoices.pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(baos.size()));
    response.addCookie(new Cookie("fileDownloadToken", fileDownloadToken));

    baos.writeTo(response.getOutputStream());
    response.getOutputStream().flush();
    response.getOutputStream().close();
```

…

the javascript that reads the cookie:

```
function startDownloadFileBlockUI() {

    var token = new Date().getTime(); //use the current timestamp as the token value

    $('#fileDownloadToken').val(token);

    //calls periodically the function at specified interval of 1000 ms (1sg) 
        idFileDownloadCheckTimer = setInterval(function () {

        var cookieValue = $.cookie("fileDownloadToken");
        if (cookieValue == token) {
            finishDownloadFileBlockUI();
        }

    }, 1000);    

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem reading another SO answer. The $.cookie can only read cookies under the current document path, In my case when the cookie is added to the head response the current document path differs of the path when it try to read the cookie. In Firefox and Chrome the url didn't change when the file is download so the path is the same when added and read the cookie.

To solve this, I only need to set the root path in the cookie before add it to the response header:

```
cookie.setPath("/")
```